# Laravel 4 + Blade, but MySQL is not encoded in UTF-8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

We are developing a new site against a legacy database with Laravel 4.

The database is read-only and we can't convert it.

We have

```
'charset' => 'cp1251'
```

in the connection, but when we try to output a string via Blade, we get

```
htmlentities(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument
```

Digging deeper we see that:

```
{{{ $shopProduct->product->sname }}}
```

compiles to:

```
<h2><?php echo e($shopProduct->product->sname); ?></h2>
```

where

```
function e($value)
{
    return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}
```

Is there a way to make either `Eloquent` or `PDO` to get non-UTF-8 encoding (`cp1251`) from MySQL and actually get to use `UTF-8` in models?

Note: we can't change database encoding on server - it's beyond our control.

Comment: just make it `'charset' => 'utf8'`

Comment: Worked! Wow, in retrospect this is "common sense" ;) Can you make it into an answer, so I can choose it? :) Thank you!

Comment: Database encoding in app/config/database.php?

Comment: Yes, that was the solution - to change the `'charset' => 'cp1251'` to `'charset' => 'utf8'` in `app/config/database.php`

Answer (score 2):

Set the charset to utf8.

```
'charset' => 'utf8'
```

Comment: also check the character encoding for each field in each table. if it's VARCHAR or TEXT, they may keep their old encoding